# Другой alert при повторном клике

Tags: javascript

Создал простенькую анимацию текста. Написал скрипт, который при клике выключает анимацию и выводит сообщение *"Анимация текста выключена"*. Хотел сделать так, чтобы при повторном клике анимация запускалась и выводилось уже другое сообщение "*Анимация текста снова работает"*, **анимация запускается, но нужное мне сообщение не появляется =(**

```js
let Second_text = document.querySelector(".second_text"); 

Second_text.addEventListener('click', function(e){  

if(Second_text){
this.classList.toggle('no_animation');
alert('Анимация текста выключена');
}

else{
alert('Анимация текста снова работает'); // Это сообщение должно выводиться при повторном клике
}

});
```

```css
.second_text{
width:400px;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-size:40px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:arial;
animation: 2s neon-2 alternate-reverse infinite;
position:absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
padding-bottom:60px;
}

.no_animation{
animation: none;    
}

@keyframes neon-2 {
from {
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #87CEEB,
0 0 10px #87CEFA,
0 0 15px #00BFFF,
0 0 20px #1E90FF;
}
to {
text-shadow: 0 0 20px #7478AE,
0 0 35px #7478AE,
0 0 40px #7478AE,
0 0 50px #7478AEk,
0 0 800px #7478AE;
}
}
```

```html
<p class="second_text">
Я ТЕБЕ ПОКУШАТЬ ПРИНЕС =)
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```js
...
this.classList.toggle('no_animation');
if(this.classList.contains('no_animation'))
  alert('Анимация текста выключена');
else
  alert('Анимация текста снова работает');    
...
```

Comment: Что здесь делает contains?

Comment: @Хлебушек проверяет наличие класса у элемента `Second_text`

Comment: А можно пожалуйста подробнее. Проверит класс а дальше что? Если класса нет, что будет?

Comment: @Хлебушек максимально подробно [DOMTokenList.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains). Проверяет наличие класса у элемента, если класс есть - `true`, иначе - `false`

Comment: Если false, то скрипт внутри if не сработает?

Comment: @Хлебушек именно. [Условное ветвление](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)

Comment: Да я помню, просто иногда забываю элементарные вещи из-за большого потока инфы каждый день.